# Configuring External Tools IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have configured an External tool in Eclipse and it works fine in Eclipse.
I want to do the same in IntelliJ.

Here are the settings for my external tool in Eclipse.

[image]

I have configured so far in IntelliJ

[image]

When I run this tool in IntelliJ. I am shown the following Error.

```
C:\jython2.5.2\bin\jython.bat ${workspace_loc:/jythonTest/uploadScript.py} ${workspace_loc}${selected_resource_path} 127.0.0.1 maxadmin password
IOError: [Errno 2] File not found - C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\workspace\jythonTest\${workspace_loc:\jythonTest\uploadScript.py} (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Edit: I am following this blog [Upload jython scripts](http://maximoscripting.stroske.de/upload-jython-scripts-from-eclipse-to-maximoicd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "macros" you're using in Eclipse (`${workspace_loc}` and the like) to set the command line parameters are different for IDEA. Use the "Insert Macro" button on the right side to find the equivilant IDEA macro for the paths you're trying to pass to your program.